# MySQL Invalid datetime format

Tags: mysql, yii, timestamp

I got this error when I'm trying to insert the value 2016-03-27T03:15:51.213 to the column with the data type 'timestamp' in my Yii1 app:

```
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2016-03-27T03:15:51.213' for column 'created' at row 1.
```

The strangest thing, when I try to insert a 2016-03-27T13:15:51.213 value - everythin's ok. What's wrong?

I use OpenServer on my Windows machine with PHP 5.6 and MySql 5.7

Comment: have you tried  2016-03-27T3:15:51.213? (No 0 before the 3)

Comment: *`2016-03-27 03:15:51`* just try with this

Comment: Your format is fine : 2016-03-27T03:15:51.213
You can try it there : https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatype/datatype-dateparse.html

If there is an error there and that 2016-03-27T13:15:51.213 works 
, it's comming from somewhere else. Can you give us the table and the query that you tried ?

Comment: @RealCheeseLord yes, I've tried. The same error.

Comment: @Latsuj sorry but it is a confidential info

Comment: Finally, I think, the bug is because of the MySQL-version...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the solution. The reason of the problem was on my Windows machine. I had an active option "Automatic transition to winter and summer time".

So, because of this option my computer didn't know about time between 3AM and 4AM when the timezone changes, because when the option is turned on, the given time does not physically exist))) So simple)

When I turned off this option on my PC and reboot it, the message had disappeared from logs.

BTW: this problem won't appear at PCs with Linux and UTC-settings without automatic transitions to winter and summer time.

Hope my answer will be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this. First create a datetime object from the string datetime

```
$datetime = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("2016-03-27T13:15:51.213"));// Output = 2016.03.27 01:15:51
```

And then use this $datetime in the sql query.

Comment: my problem was with 2016-03-27T03:15:51.213, not with 2016-03-27T13:15:51.213

Comment: Whatever the date is that solution will work. Why the down vote? Could you please enlighten me?